# AngularFire binding doesn't affect template expressions

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-template, angularfire2

Let me first say that I'm very new to angular..
My problem is that following the example at [AngularFire 2 - Retrieving data as lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md) I've displayed a list of data from a firebase database in a table.

On one of the columns I've added this condition in the template:

```
{{local.authorized?'Approved':'Rejected'}}
```

This is supposed to replace a "true/false" with "Approved/rejected"

The data binding works if I show only the raw value, but if I use the condition it doesn't interpret the value change..

Can you help please?

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 locais: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.locais = db.list('locais');

  }
  addLocal(newName: string) {
    this.locais.push({ text: newName });
  }
  updateLocal(key: string, newText: string) {
    this.locais.update(key, { authorized: newText });
  }
  deleteLocal(key: string) {    
    this.locais.remove(key); 
  }
  deleteEverything() {
    this.locais.remove();
  }

}
```

Comment: I can not see variable with a name local  in your AppComponent as its shown in your template

Comment: @mohamadrabee "locais" is the plural of "local" and that variable is only used to refer to the position(object) on the list that you're at.

Comment: So add more from your template please